# Diff_drive_controller not subscribing to /cmd_vel

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-control, diff-drive-controller, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, my team is working on a differential drive robot and trying to decide if the `diff_drive_controller` is a good fit for our project. We have been borrowing and adapting code from projects like [My_ROS_mobile_robot](https://github.com/eborghi10/my_ROS_mobile_robot), [ros_control_boilerplate](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/ros_control_boilerplate), and the [hardware_interface tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20hardware%20interface).

Our problem right now is that when we launch all the nodes that we believe we need, there is no subscription to /cmd_vel as we would expect, given `diff_drive_controller`'s [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller#Subscribed_Topics).
I'll leave some snippets of our code below. [Here is a link to our full repository](https://github.com/campusrover/rover_4_core/tree/hardware_interface), with relevant code to this problem located in the hw_interface and launch directories.

Here is our relevant code:
diff_drive.launch:

```
<launch>
<!-- Hardware Interface -->
<node name='hardware_interface' type='hw_interface_node' pkg='hw_inter'/>
<!-- URDF -->
<arg name="urdf_file" default="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find rover_4_core)/description/urdf/rover.urdf'" />
<param name="robot_description" command="$(arg urdf_file)" />
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
<!-- Load controller config -->
<rosparam command="load" 
          file="$(find rover_4_core)/hw_interface/config/common.yaml"/>
<rosparam command="load" 
          file="$(find rover_4_core)/hw_interface/config/control.yaml"/>

<node name="controller_spawner" 
      pkg="controller_manager" 
      type="spawner" 
      output="screen" 
      ns="/"
      args="mobile_base_controller joint_state_controller leftWheel_effort_controller rightWheel_effort_controller"/>    
</launch>
```

control.yaml:

```
my_robot:
motor_commands:
    pwm_update_frequency: 50.0
    cmd_vel_topic:
      left:  "/cmd_vel"
      right: "/cmd_vel"
  # Publish all joint states -----------------------------------
  # Creates the /joint_states topic necessary in ROS
  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50  

  # Effort Controllers ---------------------------------------
  leftWheel_effort_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointEffortController
    joint: lwheel_to_base
    pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.1, d: 10.0}
    #pid: {p: 50.0, i: 0.1, d: 0.0}
  rightWheel_effort_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointEffortController
    joint: rwheel_to_base
    pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.1, d: 10.0}
    #pid: {p: 50.0, i: 0.1, d: 0.0}
```

common.yaml:

```
mobile_base_controller:
  type        : "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
  left_wheel  : 'left_wheel'
  right_wheel : 'right_wheel'
  publish_rate: 50.0  # default: 50
  pose_covariance_diagonal : [0.001, 0.001, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000.0]
  twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000.0]

  # Wheel separation and diameter. These are both optional.
  # diff_drive_controller will attempt to read either one or both from the
  # URDF if not specified as a parameter
  wheel_separation : 0.026 # meters 
  wheel_radius : 0.0045    # meters

  # Wheel separation and radius multipliers
  wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0 # default: 1.0
  wheel_radius_multiplier    : 1.0 # default: 1.0

  # Velocity commands timeout [s], default 0.5
  cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25

  # Base frame_id
  base_frame_id: base_link #default: base_link
  # Velocity and acceleration limits
  # Whenever a min_* is unspecified, default to -max_*
  linear:
    x:
      has_velocity_limits    : true
      max_velocity           : 1.15 #1.0  # m/s
      min_velocity           : -1.15 #-0.5 # m/s
      has_acceleration_limits: true
      max_acceleration       : 5.0 #0.8  # m/s^2
      min_acceleration       : -1.0 #-0.4 # m/s^2
      has_jerk_limits        : true
      max_jerk               : 5.0  # m/s^3
  angular:
    z:
      has_velocity_limits    : true
      max_velocity           : 50.0 #1.7  # rad/s
      has_acceleration_limits: true
      max_acceleration       : 1.5  # rad/s^2
      has_jerk_limits        : true
      max_jerk               : 2.5  # rad/s^3

#Publish to TF directly or not
enable_odom_tf: true

#Name of frame to publish odometry in
odom_frame_id: odom

# Publish the velocity command to be executed. 
# It is to monitor the effect of limiters on the controller input.
publish_cmd: true
```

Finally here's a [link to our hardware interface node](https://github.com/campusrover/rover_4_core/blob/hardware_interface/hw_interface/hw_interface.cpp), because it's too long to include here. We appreciate your time and help!

EDIT: console output of `diff_drive.launch`

```
    $ roslaunch rover_4_core diff_drive.launch 
... logging to /home/nate/.ros/log/4f103afa-5e62-11ea-8022-b827eb2d9e86/roslaunch-natebook-9951.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
started roslaunch server http://172.20.171.238:38857/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /enable_odom_tf: True
 * /mobile_base_controller/angular/z/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /mobile_base_controller/angular/z/has_jerk_limits: True
 * /mobile_base_controller/angular/z/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /mobile_base_controller/angular/z/max_acceleration: 1.5
 * /mobile_base_controller/angular/z/max_jerk: 2.5
 * /mobile_base_controller/angular/z/max_velocity: 50.0
 * /mobile_base_controller/base_frame_id: base_link
 * /mobile_base_controller/cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25
 * /mobile_base_controller/left_wheel: left_wheel
 * /mobile_base_controller/linear/x/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /mobile_base_controller/linear/x/has_jerk_limits: True
 * /mobile_base_controller/linear/x/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /mobile_base_controller/linear/x/max_acceleration: 5.0
 * /mobile_base_controller/linear/x/max_jerk: 5.0
 * /mobile_base_controller/linear/x/max_velocity: 1.15
 * /mobile_base_controller/linear/x/min_acceleration: -1.0
 * /mobile_base_controller/linear/x/min_velocity: -1.15
 * /mobile_base_controller/pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 10...
 * /mobile_base_controller/publish_rate: 50.0
 * /mobile_base_controller/right_wheel: right_wheel
 * /mobile_base_controller/twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 10...
 * /mobile_base_controller/type: diff_drive_contro...
 * /mobile_base_controller/wheel_radius: 0.0045
 * /mobile_base_controller/wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
 * /mobile_base_controller/wheel_separation: 0.026
 * /mobile_base_controller/wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0
 * /my_robot/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /my_robot/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /my_robot/leftWheel_effort_controller/joint: lwheel_to_base
 * /my_robot/leftWheel_effort_controller/pid/d: 10.0
 * /my_robot/leftWheel_effort_controller/pid/i: 0.1
 * /my_robot/leftWheel_effort_controller/pid/p: 100.0
 * /my_robot/leftWheel_effort_controller/type: effort_controller...
 * /my_robot/motor_commands/cmd_vel_topic/left: /cmd_vel
 * /my_robot/motor_commands/cmd_vel_topic/right: /cmd_vel
 * /my_robot/motor_commands/pwm_update_frequency: 50.0
 * /my_robot/rightWheel_effort_controller/joint: rwheel_to_base
 * /my_robot/rightWheel_effort_controller/pid/d: 10.0
 * /my_robot/rightWheel_effort_controller/pid/i: 0.1
 * /my_robot/rightWheel_effort_controller/pid/p: 100.0
 * /my_robot/rightWheel_effort_controller/type: effort_controller...
 * /odom_frame_id: odom
 * /publish_cmd: True
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.3

NODES
  /
    controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    hardware_interface (rover_4_core/hw_interface_node2)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://robot.dyn.brandeis.edu:11311

process[hardware_interface-1]: started with pid [9965]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [9966]
process[controller_spawner-3]: started with pid [9967]
[INFO] [1583358955.344833]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[INFO] [1583358955.386302]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1583358955.419234]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1583358955.452522]: Loading controller: mobile_base_controller
```

EDIT 2: The output of `rosnode info hardware_interface` while everything is running is as follows:

```
$ rosnode info hardware_interface
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Node [/hardware_interface]
    Publications: 
     * /left_wheel_vel [std_msgs/Float32]
     * /right_wheel_vel [std_msgs/Float32]
     * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
    
    Subscriptions: 
     * /encoder_left [std_msgs/Int64]
     * /encoder_right [std_msgs/Int64]
    
    Services: 
     * /controller_manager/list_controller_types
     * /controller_manager/list_controllers
     * /controller_manager/load_controller
     * /controller_manager/reload_controller_libraries
     * /controller_manager/switch_controller
     * /controller_manager/unload_controller
     * /hardware_interface/get_loggers
     * /hardware_interface/set_logger_level
    
    


    contacting node http://172.20.171.238:38647/ ...
Pid: 6911
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /left_wheel_vel
    * to: /serial_node
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /right_wheel_vel
    * to: /serial_node
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /encoder_left
    * to: /serial_node (http://robot:41185/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /encoder_right
    * to: /serial_node (http://robot:41185/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345887/diff_drive_controller-not-subscribing-to-/cmd_vel/) by [ndimick](https://answers.ros.org/users/52198/ndimick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-03-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-04**:
Your `.launch` file suggests you are attempting to start all of these controllers together: `mobile_base_controller joint_state_controller leftWheel_effort_controller rightWheel_effort_controller`.

That cannot work, as the effort controllers will try to claim the same resources as your `mobile_base_controller`.

Can you show the output on the console after you `roslaunch [..] diff_drive.launch`?

**Comment by [ndimick](https://answers.ros.org/users/52198/ndimick/) on 2020-03-04**:
Hi, @gvdhoorn, thanks for your help! I've edited the original question to include the console output at the bottom of the question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-05**:
If that's all there is then I'm not sure everything is being started.

Can you try launching using

```
roslaunch --screen rover_4_core diff_drive.launch
```

Is this one machine btw? Because I see this in your output:

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://robot.dyn.brandeis.edu:11311
```

If this is multi-machine then please make sure DNS is working properly (in both ways, so forward and reverse lookup).

**Comment by [ndimick](https://answers.ros.org/users/52198/ndimick/) on 2020-03-05**:
launching using

```
roslaunch --screen rover_4_core diff_drive.launch
```

produced the same console output as before. No new or additional lines.

Yes we are on a multi-machine setup, launching diff_drive.launch from a remote pc, running `roscore` on a raspberry pi attached to our hardware. We tested DNS lookups with `dig` and it is working properly both ways from both machines. Ros topics are also communicating between the two without issue.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2020-03-09**:
@gvdhoorn I am working with @ndimick. We're wondering if you (or anyone else) has further insight into the problem above and/or whether you need some more information? Thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-09**:
I find the console log you show suspicious. I'd expect a line mentioning something like "started controller .." there as well.

Try listing the controllers loaded and ascertaining their status.

Also: what is the output of `rosnode info hardware_interface` after you've started everything?

**Comment by [ndimick](https://answers.ros.org/users/52198/ndimick/) on 2020-03-09**:
Should the controller start automatically after it is spawned or does it have to be manually started inside of a node?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:
Please answer my other questions as well.

**Comment by [ndimick](https://answers.ros.org/users/52198/ndimick/) on 2020-03-10**:
I've added the output of `rosnode info hardware_interface` to the original post. it is at the very bottom of the post.

Additionally, `rosservice call /controller_manager/list_controllers "{}"` and `rosrun controller_manager controller_manager list` both produce no output. I hope that helps.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:
According to your comment, no controllers are loaded into your `hardware_interface`. That would explain why you don't see the `cmd_vel` subscription.

**Comment by [fjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/9816/fjp/) on 2020-03-18**:
@ndimick, @pitosalas, @gvdhoorn why are the two JointEffortControllers required? Isn't DiffDriveController sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the `main(..)` from the code you link in your question:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /*
    * Main loop of the hardware interface.
    */
    ros::init(argc, argv, "hw_interface");
    MyRobot robot;
    controller_manager::ControllerManager cm(&robot);
    ros::Time time_now;
    ros::Duration period_now;
    ros::Rate sleep_rate(10);
    

    while (true)
    {
        time_now = robot.get_time();
        period_now = robot.get_period(); 
        robot.read(period_now);
        cm.update(time_now, period_now);
        robot.write();
        sleep_rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

There is one thing suspiciously missing here, and that would be somewhere for ROS to actually process events. The fact that the `controller_manager` services do not produce any output is indicative of this.

Even a `hardware_interface` needs *some* time to process incoming and outgoing events, but you don't give it any.

You'll either want to call `ros::spinOnce()` somewhere in your `while` loop, or instantiate a `ros::AsyncSpinner` and start it. The latter would actually be recommended. Something like this should do the trick:

```
ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(2);
spinner.start();
```

A single thread is not enough, as there is a high potential for deadlocks.

Note that this also done in the two examples that you link: `PickNikRobotics/ros_control_boilerplate` ([here](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/ros_control_boilerplate/blob/cc7af57a111fa4913c668da2cc362b75f7450ca3/rrbot_control/src/rrbot_hw_main.cpp#L47-L50)) and `eborghi10/my_ROS_mobile_robot` ([here](https://github.com/eborghi10/my_ROS_mobile_robot/blob/c54465ba1ab76fd69c8653f7b09c4d9cd7e043da/my_robot_base/src/my_robot_base.cpp#L29)).

---

Edit: just noticed you have this:

```
while (true)
{
  [..]
}
```

This is not a good idea in a ROS node -- which a `hardware_interface` essentially is.

You'll want to check for `ros::ok()` instead.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ndimick](https://answers.ros.org/users/52198/ndimick/) on 2020-03-11**:
Thank you! adding the `ros::AsyncSpinner` did the trick. Again, thanks for your time, help and additional insights.